# How to comment out multiple line matching a regex using sed or awk

Tags: unix, regex, sed, perl, awk

I have a file that contains this:

```
[...]

location /static {
    ...
    multiple lines
    ...
}

[...]

location /static/ {
    ...
    multiple lines
    ...
}

[...]
```

And I want to get:

```
[...]

# location /static {
#     ...
#     multiple lines
#     ...
# }

[...]

# location /static/ {
#     ...
#     multiple lines
#     ...
# }

[...]
```

How can I manage to do that giving my file to an unix command?

Comment: Interesting question. +1'd ya.

Comment: I don't know unix syntax, but you could try matching the pattern `^([^\[])` and replacing with `#\1`. This will work if none of the lines between bracketed expressions have a `[` at the start of the line.

Comment: Can the multiple lines contain `}` before the closing `}`?

Comment: I would have say no but I love that your answer assumes so eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not trivial. If you can assume that each `{}` block does not contain other, nested `{}` blocks it is easier and you can do something like this:

```perl
perl -pe 'if(/location\s*\/static/){$n=1}elsif(/}/){$n=0} s/^/#/ if $n==1;' file
```

This simply sets `$n` to `1` if the current line matches `location /static` and sets it back to `0` at the first `}` found after the `location/static`. Then, as long as `$n==1`, it addas a `#` to the beginning of the line. The `-p` flag causes perl to automatically loop through the input file and print each line.

Now, if you can have arbitrary depth nested blocks within the blocks you want to comment, things get more complicated. For example, if you have something like this:

```
location /static {
   if(foo){
      print "one";
   }
   elsif(bar){
      print "two";
   }
}
```

For cases like that, the simple solution above will fail and you will have to use one that keeps track of the number of open `{`. For example (this is actually a one-liner, you can copy/paste directly into your terminal, I just expanded it for clarity):

```perl
perl -pe 'if(/location\s*\/static/){$n=1;}
          elsif(/}/ && $open==0){$n=0} 
          if($n==1 && /{/){$open++} ## count open brackets
          elsif($n==1 && /}/){$open--} ## count closing brackets
          if($n==1 && $open>0){ s/^/#/}; ' file
```

Finally, if the solutions work as expected, you can add the `-i` flag do make the changes to the file itself:

```perl
perl -i -pe 'if(/location\s*\/static/){$n=1}elsif(/}/){$n=0} s/^/#/ if $n==1;' file
```

Comment: The first one forget to comment the last } line.

Comment: Something like that? `perl -pe 'if(/\s*location\s*\/static/){$n=1}elsif(/\s*}/ && $n==1){$n=0} if($n!=2){s/^/# /} if($n==0){ $n=2}' file`

Comment: And to uncomment: `perl -i -pe 'if(/^# \s*location\s*\/static/){$n=1} elsif(/^# \s*}/ && $n==1){$n=0} if($n!=2){s/^# //} if($n==0){$n=2}' filename`

Answer (score 0):

Extracting (possibly nested) delimited blocks with regular expressions is not particularly fun or easy. There is an elegant solution, though, using a module that's been shipping with Perl for a long time now (since Perl was one of your tags), viz. [Text::Balanced](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Balanced qw( extract_bracketed );

my $in = do { local $/ = undef; <> };
while( $in ) {
    my $out;
    if    ( $in =~ s/^(location\s+\S+\s+)// ) { ( $out = $1 . extract_bracketed($in) ) =~ s/^/# /mg }
    elsif ( $in =~ s/^(.*[\r\n]*)// )         { $out = $1 }
    print $out;
}
```

This script works by repeatedly consuming (extracting) and analyzing the leading part of the string, until nothing is left:

- If the leading part contains the `location` keyword, followed by whitespace (`\s+`), and something that looks like it could be an identifier (currently identified very crudely by it being a sequence of non-whitespace characters, `\S+`), then `extract_bracketed` will extract the delimited block that follows (by default, it will extract a block delimited by any of the following pairs: `[]`, `{}`, `()` or `<>`). `extract_bracketed` will correctly deal with nested, balanced delimiters inside the block to be extracted. The following substitution `s/^/# /mg` is responsible for commenting out the individual lines in the block, no matter how many lines it might contain. The block (together with the leading location keyword) is then printed out.
- Otherwise, a line (up to and including the newline character) is extracted and printed unmodified.

Some other things to note:

1. the text is read and stored in its entirety in a string (`$in`) by undefining the record separator `$/`
2. `$1` is the special variable that holds the contents of the regular expression delimited by parentheses; e.g., for `(location\s+\S+\s+)`, $1 contains the text `location /static` (including the trailing space).